# Hello, I'm receiving an HTML code error regarding img -- Attribute img not allowed on element input at this point

Tags: html, validation

i'm getting this error when validating my HTML code in validatorw3.org. Can someone assist if they recognize this error. Much thanks.

```
<input type=image img id="magnifying-glass" src="images/magnifying-glass.png" alt="magnifying glass in search bar">↩
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image  Notice that `img` is not listed as an attribute.  Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the `img` attribute from your input.

It should be this:
`<input type=image id="magnifying-glass" src="images/magnifying-glass.png" alt="magnifying glass in search bar">`

Not this: `<input type=image img id="magnifying-glass" src="images/magnifying-glass.png" alt="magnifying glass in search bar">`